# Sphinx - Let the customize HTML know the variable

Tags: python, python-sphinx

```py
# conf.py

language='en'
html_extra_path = ["customize.html"]
```

```html
<!-- customize.html -->

{{ variables }}  <!-- from the conf.py -->
{{ language }}  <!-- expected output: en -->
```

How can I let the `customize.html` know the variables is from the config?

*.. note:: assume the customize.html file is not in the documents of the theme.*

I can do it by myself with [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/), but this is not what I want.

I think [sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) already provides a way to do the things, does anyone know what is it?

Comment: You could just use a naming convention :) simple, effective...

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is not purely replace. If it does not link to the sphinx, which will cause many things not to work, such as ``pathto``, ``css_tag``, ``hasdoc``.

Comment: I worked out a solution finally and writing the answer now.
(and I see you (@bad_coder) again! you seem to be interested in the sphinx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1: modify sphinx-build.exe process

I hack the code *(i.e. you could not build with sphinx-build.exe directly)* to achieve it.

First, we observe `sphinx-build.exe` do what things.

```
# site-packages\Sphinx-x.x.x.dist-info\entry_points.txt

[console_scripts]
...
sphinx-build = sphinx.cmd.build:main
...
```

and then you know it actually calls `sphinx.cmd.build:main` to run,
you can reference it and make modifications to satisfying you.

For example:

```py
import sphinx.cmd.build
from sphinx.application import Sphinx
from sphinx.builders.html import StandaloneHTMLBuilder
from sphinx.cmd.build import patch_docutils, docutils_namespace, handle_exception, Sphinx

def setup_extra_html(app):
    html_builder = app.builder

    ctx = {attr: app.config[attr] for attr in dir(app.config) if not attr.startswith('_')}
    html_builder.globalcontext = ctx.copy()
    # Please put your HTML to the ``templates_path`` that you define, since it concept about the BuiltinTemplateLoader.pathchain
    pagename = 'disqus_statistic'  # <-- your HTML, you can set it on the conf.py and then get it with ``ctx``
    templatename = f'{pagename}.html'

    html_builder.handle_page(pagename=pagename, addctx=dict(), templatename=templatename, outfilename=None)


def your_build_main(*args):

    ...

    try:
        with patch_docutils(source_dir)), docutils_namespace():
            app = Sphinx(...)
            if isinstance(app.builder, StandaloneHTMLBuilder):
                setup_extra_html(app)
            app.build(force_all=False, filenames)
            return app.statuscode
        except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt) as exc:
            ...

cmd_list = [source_dir, output_dir, '-b', 'html', ...]
sphinx.cmd.build.build_main = your_build_main  # override it.
sphinx.cmd.build.main(cmd_list)  # it will call sphinx.cmd.build.build_main
```

And now, the following contents will work as you expected.

```html
<!-- original disqus_statistic.html  -->

{%- if html_favicon %}
  <a href="{{ pathto(html_favicon, 1) }}">Test Icon</a>
{%- endif %}

{{ language }}
```

*you should complete the detail by yourself since the code is too long.
or you can refer my script of [sphinx_cmd_build.py](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/typing-game/blob/release/sphinx_cmd_build.py#L97-#L107)*

---

## Solution 2: add the plugin (extension)

tl;dr

```py
# your_extension.py

from sphinx.application import Sphinx
from sphinx.builders.html import StandaloneHTMLBuilder
import pathlib


def expand_init_builder(app):
    Sphinx._init_builder(app)
    do_something(app)

def setup(app: Sphinx):
    app.add_config_value('config_value_define_by_you', default='', rebuild=True)
    app._init_builder = lambda: expand_init_builder(app)

def do_something(app: Sphinx):
    user_config = {attr: app.config[attr] for attr in dir(app.config) if not attr.startswith('_')}  # all variable of conf.py
    # user_config.update(...)  # Hard coding is fine, but not recommend.
    user_config.update(dict(Path=pathlib.Path))  # recommend you, it's useful.
    html_builder: StandaloneHTMLBuilder = app.builder
    html_builder.globalcontext = user_config
    html_builder.handle_page(pagename=page_name, addctx=dict(), templatename=template_name, outfilename=None)
```

```py
# conf.py
# sys.path.insert(...)
extensions.append('your_extension')  # Make sure your scrips can found in sys.path.

# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-templates_path
templates_path = ['_templates/sphinx_rtd_theme']  # I hope you know what I mean... see the above link.
# I put my_html.html in ``_templates/sphinx_rtd_theme/my_html.html``

config_value_define_by_you = "https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/typing-game"
```

```html
<!-- my_html.html -->

{{ Path(config_value_define_by_you).name }}  <!-- render result: typing-game -->
```

### Long story *(explain solutions2)*

Sphinx-build.exe doing what things?

- init  # <-- and this one is not we cared.
- create an instance of Sphinx(), the instance is app. i.e. `app = Sphinx(...)`
- app.build

  - it calls the builder to start building, the builder format which defines by the user, in my case the build format is HTML, so its builder is `StandaloneHTMLBuilder`

And then, you know all files that are created by the builder.
The idea is: if we can **get the builder**, then we can do anything we want.

You will find the builder that is creat after the `Sphinx(...)`,
so the solutions one, I tell you `setup_extra_html` after the `app = Sphinx(...)`

If you don't like to write these codes and think it's too complex.

The second way is to write the extensions,
the concept is the same as the above -- try to **get the builder**

you see the `Sphinx(...)` its constructor, and you find the code as below

```
class Sphinx:
    def __init__(...):
        ...

        # load all user-given extension modules
        for extension in self.config.extensions:
            self.setup_extension(extension)  # <-- the extension you write

        ...

        # create the builder
        self.builder = self.create_builder(buildername)  <-- this is we want
        self._init_env(freshenv)
        self._init_builder()
```

And then, you know the normal way to create the extensions which couldn't get the builder,
but you notice that if you do something after the self._init_builder() finished, then it's ok.

I provide my projects for your reference.
The real things that I want is, I want to create a page and I hope it can count the numbers of comments for each article, and show me.
You will understand, if I don't use the sphinx, but choose naming convention, then I must hard code a lot of things.

- solution 1: https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/typing-game/commit/376c9e20eac4a3c9b269b5bfbc8adb85ad9f6d36
- solution 2: https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/typing-game/commit/69411e15f1ace853edcafafc14759ba79b7ac288
- demo: https://carsonslovoka.github.io/typing-game/en/doc.html#statistic  -> and then, click counts of the Disqus.

  - [original HTML](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/typing-game/commit/376c9e20eac4a3c9b269b5bfbc8adb85ad9f6d36?diff=unified#diff-21e495856d8a96d1c22136cb482350d6)

*I hope you will get help and think it useful!*

Comment: This is some serious Sphinx/docutils hacking. How do you guarantee there aren't unintended side-effects? I'm still learning about several aspects of Sphinx and decided to leave anything HTML and "costume directive" related for later. (I'm happy when I can adequately document my projects with as little overhead as possible...And that alone has been hard enough!)

Comment: Serious hacking? If so, I think it must do a lot of modified for original, but I don't.
I update the answer, and now, you can just add an extension to achieve it.